# What is the effective population size of a simple two deme metapopulation?

Tags: genetics, evolution, theoretical-biology, population-genetics, population-biology

I am confused as to how to compute the effective population size $N_e$ of a theoretical structured population. Let's consider here a simple case study.

Imagine a 2-deme metapopulation. Each deme is of constant size $N$ with a (forward and backward) migration rate $m$. Mating is random within each deme.

What is the effective population size of such population? In other words, how fast does the population loses heterozygosity through time?

Comment: this book looks useful - see page 109 (there is restricted access) https://books.google.se/books?hl=en&lr=&id=pjo5FP5gpFIC&oi=fnd&pg=PA87&dq=effective+population+size+metapopulation&ots=J_z6Ygwl_X&sig=O0Op0mXXYKHdW2OweT8CJKew79Y&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=migration&f=false

Comment: There is no single effective population size when there is population structure. Suppose structure is strong, $Nm \ll 1$. If you start with very high heterozygosity, it will first decay at a rate close to $1/N$, then more slowly at a rate close to $m$ after the diversity within each deme has been lost.